# Exponential and ln function

Tags: exponential-function, transcendental-equations

It seems quite simple but how would I find the exact solution for:

$$\exp(x) = -\ln(x) $$

I'm not too sure where to start?

Comment: I suspect that a closed form solution doesn't exist.  I don't have a way of proving this, though.

Comment: Using [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) and iterating $\;\displaystyle f(x)=x-\frac{e^x+\frac 1x}{e^x+\log(x)}\;$ to get (after $5$ iterations starting with $x=1$) $\approx 0.26987413757344922387738245$.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni could you expand on this into an answer please?

Comment: @jim: I added an answer (my fraction was reverted previously sorry...)

Comment: There is a solution of a series of a Bell polynomial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't bet on a closed form here and use [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) iterations to get :

\begin{align}
x_0&:=1\\
x_{n+1}&:=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}\\
x_{n+1}&:=x_n-\frac{e^{x_n}+\log(x_n)}{e^{x_n}+\dfrac 1{x_n}}\;\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
x_0&=1\\
x_1& = 0.2689414213699951207488407582\\
x_2& = 0.2698730572541564559160264039\\
x_3& = 0.2698741375720040468246780600\\
x_4& = 0.2698741375734492238773798650\\
x_5& = 0.2698741375734492238773824512\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

$$e^x=\log \frac{1}{x}$$
take the e for both side
$$e^{e^x}=\frac{1}{x}$$
hence
$$x=\frac{1}{e^{e^x}}$$
$$x=\frac{1}{e^{e^{\frac{1}{e^{e^{...}}}}}}$$

Comment: @Winther I think now there is no problem happens with the new form.

Comment: Yes that works much better. The solution is now an attractive fixpoint of the map $x\to e^{-e^{x}}$ (apposed to before where the fixpoint was a repeller) so the recurrence $x_{n+1} = e^{-e^{x_n}}$ converges to the desired solution for any initial guess $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^x=-\ln(x)$$

We see, your equation is an irreducible polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($e^x,\ln(x)$). We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (elementary operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.
I don't know if the equation has solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

$x\to e^t$:
$$e^{e^t}=-\ln(e^t)$$
$$e^{e^t}=-t-2k\pi i\ \ \ (\forall k\in\mathbb{Z})$$

We see, we cannot solve the equation with Lambert W in the general case, but with Hyper Lambert W:

$$1=-(t+2k\pi i)e^{-e^t}$$
$$(t+2k\pi i)e^{-e^t}=-1$$
$t\to u-2k\pi i$:
$$ue^{-e^{u-2k\pi i}}=-1$$
$$ue^{-e^{-2k\pi i}e^u}=-1$$
$$G(-e^{-2k\pi i};u)=-1$$
$$u=HW(-e^{-2k\pi i};-1)$$
$$t=HW(-e^{-2k\pi i};-1)-2k\pi i$$
$$x=e^{HW(-e^{-2k\pi i};-1)-2k\pi i}$$

So we have a closed form for $x$, and the representations of Hyper Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Galidakis, I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)